# Wordpress media upload "HTTP error"

Tags: php, uploads, media, media-library, nginx

When I try to upload an image, I get the following error: `HTTP error`.

I know this problem has been solved hundred times but I can't find the right answer form my configuration.

In the php.ini, I have the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
max_file_uploads = 20
post_max_size = 50M
```

And in my wp-config.php, I added:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '120MB');
```

I am using nginx, so every answers using .htaccess are not useful for my case.
How can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to fix my problem.

In my nginx config file (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) I added `client_max_body_size 100m;` at the end of the `#Basic Settings` in the `http {}` section.

I hope this answer will help some of you and please tell me if there is any better solution to this problem.